# Problem with audio output on OS X 10.10.4

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, audio

I recently upgraded my OS to Yosemite 10.10.4

After done my volume icon is greyed out and no sound is found. This is not the bug where it is set on HDMI since when i open output there is no internal speakers nor does it find a pair of head phones.

It will still detect bluetooth and HDMI sound.

Any takers on a good answer?

Comment: to clarify for me, you do have a sound on hdmi output and on the bluetooth. It does not show internal speakers in the syst pref sound ?

Comment: could you tell us what is says in the About this Mac- Audio

Comment: It looks like all my internal audio drivers are gone. 

I can listen through HDMI and Bluetooth, but there is no core audio process nor can i find the internal speakers or a plugged in soundsytem/headphones in the sound preferences. 

it seems like the sound drivers have gone missing.

Comment: In that case, your Yosemite installation did not go well. Redo it.

Comment: What would be the best way to go about a reinstalation of Yosemite?

Comment: If you kept the Yosemite download on your USB then no brainier. If you did not use the "cmd+r" during booth and follow the instruction to restore. Here depends if you already have the restore on you hard drive it will automatically use that, if not it will automatically get it from Internet. The whole process can take up to 3 hours depending on your Internet speed.

Answer (score 1):

While I've never experienced this issue in Yosemite, I did have issues with audio output on an older OS. If I remember correctly, my solution was to reset the core audio.

The following is reason to believe some have experienced loss of audio in 10.9: http://www.imore.com/losing-audio-os-x-mavericks-heres-what-you-can-do-about-it

This thread shows a means of automating the process, in case that solves your problem: http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/create-a-service-to-reboot-core-audio.1697918/

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the question and welcome to Ask Different!  Links can sometimes go bad so if you can, it would be good to edit your answer with explanations from the references. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Chris. Thank you a lot for your help.

Sadly there is no coreaudio process at all on my computer, it is like all my core audio drivers has disappeared. I can still listen through bluetooth and HDMI